# How Covert unknown date format to UTC in Java

Tags: java

I have to convert the following time to UTC but I don't know what format the current time is in. How do I convert it to UTC using Java?
Unknown format:

```
1561554154352
```

It clear to me which or how to do it based on the Java Date documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't so much a Date as it is an offset to an epoch (specifically, the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC). To convert it to a date, pass that number to the date constructor. Like,

```
long epochTime = 1561554154352L;
System.out.println(new Date(epochTime));
```

Outputs

```
Wed Jun 26 09:02:34 EDT 2019
```

Comment: Or use `Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochTime)` for newer API.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you from Zulu(UTC):

```
System.out.println("Current elapsed from epoch => " + System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("Convereted to UTC =>" + Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
```